# Can you set the Same-Origin Policy to be more strict?

Tags: html, css, same-origin-policy

I have a situation where users are able to define CSS for specific areas of the site that they maintain. They are able to insert remote resources into this document, and subsequently log IP requests made to these resources by guest users visiting their pages.

Short of adding a purification system that filters remote URLs, is there a way to instruct the client not to make *ANY* foreign requests? My site is 100% self-contained at the origin and makes no foreign CDN requests. I basically want it so that any foreign request is blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) can limit the resources that can be included in the site.

For example, this would limit the page to load scripts only from its own domain and from Google domain

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

More options, including for loading styles

- `style-src` is script-src’s counterpart for stylesheets.
- `connect-src` limits the origins to which you can connect (via XHR, WebSockets, and EventSource)
- `frame-src` Use child-src instead.
- `img-src` defines the origins from which images can be loaded.
- `media-src` restricts the origins allowed to deliver video and audio.

Comment: Not a terrible suggestion but hardly bulletproof. It's down to the browser to enforce this or not and a determined "attacker" could easily choose to use a [browser which does not support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy).

Comment: Well yes, it's down to the browser to be safe software or not. If a user is using an unsafe browser, that's a choice they made. How is it important what browser an attacker is using?

Comment: I used 'attacker' in inverted commas to refer to anyone who wants to break OP's policy. An example: if a user of an unsupported browser were to insert an external CSS sheet, the result they would see would be perfectly fine. They'd then be completely unaware that the entire layout of the site was broken for any visitors using browsers supporting Content Security Policy.